# SQL Select the ids where it's greater than the id when it was created

Tags: sql

I'm trying to write a SQL SELECT statement where I can select the newly created ID's after it was first created. Problem is I don't know the exact date of which ID is the lowest, and I don't know what number the ID starts from. So let's say if I need to select ID's 22, 23 because 21 has the earliest created date. What I tried.

```
select c.casesoffensesid from casesoffenses c where c.casesoffensesid > c.casesoffensesid where c.created_at;

select c.casesoffensesid from casesoffenses c group by Min(c.created_at);
```

Somewhere along these lines but unsure if I need a subquery for this. Does Min work for dates like 2017-08-23 or is there another query I can use to check this. Thanks still learning.

[image]

Comment: Sample data would help your question.

Comment: yes min works for dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you need:

```
select c.casesoffensesid from casesoffenses c where c.casesoffensesid > 21
```

Because the ouput of this is 21

```
SELECT min(casesoffensesid) from casesoffenses where created_at >= '2017-08-23'
```

You can combine those queries, and do:

```
select c.casesoffensesid 
from casesoffenses c 
where c.casesoffensesid > (
     SELECT min(casesoffensesid) 
     from casesoffenses 
     where created_at >= '2017-08-23')
```

Comment: The user does not know the created date or the id which belongs to the created date. So in the query I wouldn't be able to use exact values

Comment: If you know the date, above should work, If you know nothing, than  no answer might fit, because there is no `GUESS()` function in SQL.

Comment: I see maybe I was thinking too much. Thanks for the feedback. I think I can work off of this answer :D